# Angularjs "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized" error in chrome

Tags: angularjs, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I have an angularjs application which is consuming a WebAPI created using WCF.

Angularjs application is making call to a WebAPI to fetch client details.
When i run both the projects (angularjs and WCF project) on my local machine. Everything works fine.

After deploying the project on development server I am facing issue while testing my angularjs application in chrome. Chrome fails to load the client details.

I checked the requests made by angularjs application using fiddler. I found that there are two calls made my angularjs application to webAPI, even though in code there is only one call in code,

Following is the code used in angular app

```
return $http({
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            url: $rootScope.models.ServiceURL + "/ServicerClient?clientName=" + searchTextSmallLetters,
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }           
        });
```

First request logged in Fiddler :

```
GET /PXTRAService.svc/ServicerClient?clientName=volvo HTTP/1.1
```

First request retunrs following error :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

Next request logged in Fiddler has Security section in request header:

```
GET /PXTRAService.svc/ServicerClient?clientName=volvo HTTP/1.1
```

[image]

Second request retunrs the expected result.

Same scenario is occuring in IE, but IE angular application redeners the fetched results correctly.

Is there any way to fix this issue in chrome?

Comment: can you show what your call looks like?

Comment: I have updated my question with angularjs call.

Comment: You need to pass login token in your headers